# Sorting in text file through program in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, user-interface

I am using Qt5.2.1 and I made a program that stores some values(like name, number, other details...) in a text file. I want to arrange this information according to the name.

Something like this.

A

Alan 24140239 some_other_info

Avril 64376334 some_other_info

B

bob 532523 some_other_info

And so on

How do I do this? I have little programming experience so try to keep it simple please :)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I this?
A gentle push in the right direction is what i need...
step by step instructions are super awesome :D

Comment: I think you need to provide more details. Is your question how to sort a text file?

Comment: setup a structure that has name, number and the other details.  put individual elements in a vector of those elements.  write the less than operator for that structure and use std::sort.  the less than operator should sort on the elements in your structure

Comment: @riklund Yes that's my question but its kinda tricky ( for me atleast) I want the sorted elements under Alphabets ( like I showed in the question above)

Comment: @RobbieE Actually I have no tried anything yet... I wanted to know before Started doing it.

Comment: @DannyK whoa man! I am complete noob... try to come down a little bit. I understood about making the structure but after that all went over my head.

Comment: @user121273 Use `QMap<QString,QString>` which is sorted by key: repeat in loop { read line, parse out the part you want to sort with, insert to QMap with the part you parsed out as key and entire line as value } then iterate the QMap values in order { write value as a line to new file }

Comment: The point about sorting is have the data in a container which amounts to an organized array.  I used std::vector.  Check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/ for std::vector. 'the method/function push_back adds an element to the vector.  Once you have the data in the vector then you can sort the data.  Before you get the data in the container you have to store the data, hence the data structure.  the data could also have been stored in a class.  If you are new to Qt/C++, then the structure definition is something you'll need to research.  google "c++ structs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is quick and dirty but should give you the idea.
I used a structure because all the elements are public by default with C++
I imagine Qt has convenience functions to do some of this work.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct my_data_t
{
    std::string m_name;
    int m_number;

    // default constructor
    my_data_t( std::string name="", int number = 0) : 
    m_name(name), m_number(number) {}

    // less than operator
    bool operator <(my_data_t b) const ;
};

// less than operator implementation ( I might have the const not quite right
// i struggle with const correctness.

bool my_data_t::operator<(my_data_t b) const 
{
    int32_t t = m_name.compare( b.m_name);

    if( t > 0 ) {
        return false;
    }
    else if( t < 0 )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if( m_number > b.m_number )
    {
        return true;
    }

    // add other tests 
    // refer to std::sort
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv )
{

    std::vector<my_data_t> data;
    my_data_t d3("Tom", 29) ;
    my_data_t d4("Jill", 22);
    data.push_back( my_data_t("Tom", 32) ); 
    data.push_back( my_data_t("Jack", 31) );
    data.push_back( d3 );
    data.push_back( d4 );

    std::cout <<  "Before sorting \n" << std::endl;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << "name, number:\t" << 
            data[i].m_name << 
            " " << 
            data[i].m_number << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( data.begin(), data.end() );

    std::cout <<  "After sorting \n" << std::endl;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << "name, number:\t" << 
            data[i].m_name << 
            " " << 
            data[i].m_number << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[cppreference std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

// compiling with cygwin

$ g++ -o sort sort.cpp

// running the example
$ ./sort.exe

Before sorting

name, number:   Tom 32
name, number:   Jack 31
name, number:   Tom 29
name, number:   Jill 22

After sorting

name, number:   Jack 31
name, number:   Jill 22
name, number:   Tom 32
name, number:   Tom 29

Comment: Thanx a ton...I do a faint idea how to do this now...let me try this. Thanx again. You're a life saver :D